# Will my own deleted, non-closed, flagged `useful`posts be completely un-associated from my Stack Overflow account?

Tags: support, flags, deleted-questions, post-ban

I had five questions which were poorly received (3 downvoted by single votes and all 5 with no answers) by the Stack Overflow community, and therefore I had deleted those.

Yesterday when I was not able to post my second question in a day.

I thought it's because of my history of poorly received questions.

I thought of flagging those questions for moderator's attention and in note I wrote

> "I want to delete these questions permanently and completely
>   un-associate from my stackoverflow account. Don't want to see those
>   questions in `Recently deleted Questions` too".

All my five flags were accepted as `useful`.

The moderator who reviewed it wrote:

> "You really don't need to flag us for all of these. Deletion is
>   perfectly fine."

Will my deleted (but not-closed) and flagged posts (which were accepted by moderator as `useful`) be completely un-associated from my Stack Overflow account?

Now please note: I don't wanted to un-associate those questions as I was not allowed to ask more questions a day. But I wanted to completely remove those from my account; from section `Questions" >> More >> Recently deleted questions` too. **Since I had deleted those**.

I had such one deleted answer too. I flagged that too and wrote a note to a moderator.

> "This was much low quality answer given by me; rather It would have
>   been a comment. As User has already accepted other answer, and I too feel
>   it is the best one; I want to delete this answer permanently and want
>   to un-associate from my Stack Overflow account permanently"

It too was accepted as useful flag and I got the reply:

> "You really don't need to flag us for all of these. Deletion is
>   perfectly fine."

Will that answer be completely un-associated from my Stack Overflow account?

Comment: I don't think the moderator who processed those flags understood why you were asking to disassociate the posts from your account. We don't generally disassociate posts to help people get out of a ban. That would be counter-productive in most cases. Some of those posts were deleted by you, and they don't have any downvotes. You could just undelete them yourself to help you get out of the ban.

Comment: Okay..
Now let's forget about ban. In general case If I want to completely unassociate any post from my account; then what I can do? I was banned first time may be because my yesterday's post was downvoted :(

Comment: and it is `not when` (not now) am trying to unassociate those deleted posts from my account; am trying to un-associate those since I had deleted those

Comment: @BilltheLizard Thanks buddy; I would undelete my posts which were not downvoted. (I still don't feel that will be useful for me; coz I have answers for those questions. While posting those questions next time; I had improved those and I have answers too. If I undelete those posts; I feel those posts will unnecessarily appear in google search). But what about deleted-downvoted posts? Can I completely un-associate those from my account? On the basis of less research effort (then :p ) by post owner?

Comment: That's not really a good reason to ask a moderator to disassociate them. Deleting them already gives back any reputation you lost, and it prevents further downvotes and hides the post from most users. We don't really need the extra work of disassociating posts when there's no real gain.

Comment: @BilltheLizard
#Noted;
Buddy; I was trying to un-associate those since I had deleted those. The other thing It's fine If am loosing the reputation I have got by deleting those; But Can I completely un-associate those?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96732/226203 may be of some help.

Comment: @BillyMailman Hmmmm.
Buddy Thanks..
But I do not meant it :)
For me `un-associate the post from my account means delete the post permanently and it should not appear in my recently deleted questions too :)

Comment: @BilltheLizard Buddy: I meant it's fine if am loosing 100 Reputation (But surely not more than that :p) for permanently deleting a post; But I don't want to give an impression to myself that.. `I had asked a bad question` :p
(Coz my deleted questions are not visible to all community members. So nothing is related to them :) )

And if I wanted just to remove the ban on me- (may be a single question in 90 minutes) then better I would have preferred to undelete my deleted posts. But it's not the case. I want to delete them as those are low quality posts.

Comment: Is the FBI gonna inspect your account ? If not then go into your memory crtl+A all Bad-posts-by-me and delete !!

Comment: Now am confused :p
Two upvotes and two downvotes from community to this question :P
am confused:
`Whether my question is good or bad one` :P

Comment: It's tough to tell what it is you're trying to accomplish here.  Both deletion *and* disassociation?  Usually, only one or the other is needed.  Both seems like overkill.  What need is there for this?

Comment: @fbueckert Buddy; I meant either permanent deletion Or Un-associating those from my account. In short 'I don't want those questions under section:
`Questions" >> More >>  Recently deleted questions`

Comment: I understand that.  I'm questioning the *need* for this.  *Why* do you want this?  What is this going to accomplish?

Comment: @fbueckert   (1)`I don't want to give an impression to myself that.. I had asked a low quality question - If I would have put some more efforts - may be 2-3 days :p I would have got answer instead of single downvote on 3 each questions `

Comment: After seeing the downvotes here.. I feel to delete this question too :(

I feel this is a good question. I don't feel this is an exact duplicate question or has an answer(such as the very first comment on post) elsewhere :)
If yes so; please let me know.

Comment: I believe you're getting downvotes because it's extremely hard to figure out what you're trying to do, here.  There doesn't seem to be any actual need here, except salving your ego.  If possible, try changing your outlook to see them as mistakes, and take them to heart.  That will help you from making it happen again.

Comment: @fbueckert
Thank you :)

Comment: @fbueckert Buddy..   Another thing I wanted to dis-associate those as `I have heard such few deleted questions can make you to prevent ask more questions a day/week.` and I don't want to happen it to me :)

Comment: And that's exactly why this will probably not happen.  Disassociation isn't meant to be used as an end run around the system.

Comment: @fbueckert Ohk.. 
Thanks bro :)
Now I have thought of a solution for this. Next time I ask a question; I'll undelete my previous question and replace it with new question :) Let that undeleted question might been asked before 6 months

Comment: If you're coming up with workarounds that are preventing you from posting something, I would highly recommend fixing the root issue, not trying to do an end run around the system.  That tends to be viewed as an abuse of the site.

Comment: @fbueckert    Ohk :)
Sure bro. :)

Comment: @BilltheLizard -- Why not post your "comment" as an Answer?

Comment: @martinf I wasn't the mod who processed those flags, and I don't think my comment is really a complete answer to the question being asked. More of a work-around, really. Brad posted his reasoning below, which I think stands as a better answer.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I cleared all those flags, and provided the above response. You were flagging all of your already deleted posts to be dissociated from your account. I could have declined these flags (which would have banned you from flagging, given the number of them cast), but chose to mark them as helpful so they would just go away.

Post dissociation cannot be done by a moderator. We have to call in an SE employee to manually do this in the database. SE employees are even busier than we are, so I want there to be a very good reason for me to bother them.

At the time, you were not question-banned nor answer-banned, so I saw no way that dissociating these from your account would even help you. You appeared to want them gone so that you couldn't see even the deleted stubs remaining on your profile. That didn't seem like a good enough reason to me.

Only a very small number of people can even see deleted posts, and they cannot search for them or see them within someone's profile. They have to manually go to the post itself to even see it. That's pretty well hidden, so we only step in and remove something from the database at that point if dangerous things like private information or login credentials are being exposed. Something you're simply not as proud with doesn't cross that threshold.

Therefore, I didn't think this was worth involving an employee and thought it was fine to simply leave these in a deleted state.

Comment: For what it's worth, it's fine to let people know they can contact us directly.  It's true we are busy (_very busy_ in fact), but this the sort of thing we are empowered to do. Plus, I [asked for this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124697/1438), so I might as well take my part in reaping the consiquences. ;-) That said, we'd probably say what you said: deletion ought to be sufficient.

Comment: @Brad Larson
Thank you Buddy for everything :)
This is what I wanted to know... A perfect answer :)
Happy :)

Comment: @JonEricson Thank you Sir for migrating it over here :) I had post it not at the `very correct place`. Happy to see the link you gave too :) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted/124697#124697

Comment: @JonEricson Sir, I have a question for you. Will the deleted posts will be disassociated from my account? `Or`
Can I undelete those while posting new questions(may be down a week/month) and replace those with a new question? (Will that get traffic to new questions? )Though I don't feel it's professional trick; Am curious.

Comment: @Avidan: Don't recycle questions. Only clarify them.

Comment: @Deduplicator Ok Sir; 
I won't recycle them. Thank you for the advise. By the way; can I know what do you mean by `clarify them`?

Comment: @Avidan: use the ordinary English meaning of "clarify", i.e. to make clear. If you wish to get answers on any of your deleted questions, improve them as per the site guidelines, and undelete them. If you do not wish to get answers on your deleted questions, just leave them deleted. They will remain associated with your account, but you need not worry about this.

Answer (score 17):

The only time questions ever really get dissociated from an account is when they're of fairly good quality or useful to future visitors and the user, for whatever reason, doesn't want their name on it anymore.

If the questions are of fairly low quality and can just be deleted, then that is a far better option and an acceptable form of dissociation - only users with at least 10,000 reputation would even be able to see them and, even with that privilege, they still need a direct link to the question in order to do so. They can't just go browsing around deleted posts looking at whatever they want.

Since your questions were all deleted, there's no reason to manually remove your name from them. So the more direct answer to your question is: never.

Answer (score 4):

One thing that you could do is fix the Downvoted questions that you deleted (*if possible*) and make them fit the site better then un-delete them.

Everyone on the entire Stack Exchange started with some bad posts, even if they read the rules and stuff they still didn't get it perfect the first time. Only the users that are High Rep can see deleted posts, and most of them aren't going to search for them either.

Deleted posts aren't easily found, compared to non-deleted posts.  I wouldn't stress over these first few bad posts.

Just Do Better Next Time.

We are here to help people get better at what they do.